# Did the early church condemn the teaching that God the Father is a person with a body living in space somewhere?

Tags: nature-of-god, early-church, heresy

I have spent my life under the impression that the belief that God the Father is a humanoid being possessing a body and living somewhere in the universe in a manner similar to ourselves is a named heresy condemned by the early church. Is that true? If so, what is the name of the heresy? I have met several Protestants recently who believe this but my googling hasn't yielded anything.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what denomination of protestant were they?  My experience is that at least most protestants agree that God is spirit and does not have a body like men.

Comment: @Nathaniel They were missionary baptist.

Comment: See my answer to the question [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32232/12563).

Comment: @MattGutting Wow, that is quite a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia's [list of Christian heresies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_heresies) turns up **[Audianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audianism)**.  This fourth-century group understood [Genesis 1:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis+1%3A27&version=ESV) to teach that God has a body like men.

This is a form of [anthropomorphism](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Catholic_Encyclopedia_(1913)/Anthropomorphism), which is more broadly defined by the 1913 Catholic Encyclopedia as:

> Anthropomorphism is the ascription to the Supreme Being of the form, organs, operations, and general characteristics of human nature.